# Is there a way to get proper path to image in public storage from vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have done `php artisan storage:link`.
So in .vue page the image can't be found by path: `:src="'/./storage/'+question.image"`.

My 404:

[image]

---

The image is uploaded in db:

[image]

And stored in storage/app/qImagess:

[image]

Structure of public folder:

[image]

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Miss app? :src="'/storage/app/'+question.image"

Comment: @Xiao_e_yun hello, 127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/qImagess/1385873137.png - still not found.

Comment: Maybe you should change to using php to serve the image, this is a dynamic resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to `config/filesystems.php` in:

```php
'links' => [
   ...
    public_path('qImagess') => storage_path('app/qImagess'),
],
```

then

```php
php config:clear
php artisan storage:link
```

the link should be:
`127.0.0.1:8000/qImagess/1385873137.png`

so add it to vue as:
`:src="'/'+question.image"`

Here is the Docs for that: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Can I see your public folder after doing this?

Comment: Thank you, sir for your support! It worked. Added view of `public` folder below in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of sir @AhmedAlQahtani, it is done after all.
The problem was in linking:

```
'links' => [
   ...
    public_path('qImagess') => storage_path('app/qImagess'),
],
```

This had to be outside of `drivers` in `filesystems.php`. That's why `php artisan storage:link` didn't do the job.
Here is public folder, where created proper `qImagess` folder is with uploaded images.

[image]